# How my chrome extension can be run automatically?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In this extension, if I click on the extension button and if current URL matches `http://example.com/*` or `https://example.com/*` it should be redirected to a new domain like `http://NewDomain/*` or `https://NewDomain/*`.

But I want this extension scan tab URL and perform redirection automatically in the following conditions:

1. if a new tab created or
2. if current tab URL changes

This is my code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "My Extension",
    "description": "Redirect example.com to NewDomain",
    "version": "0.1",

    "permissions":
    [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "background"
    ],

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts":
    [
      {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
var current_url = tab.url.split('/');

if(current_url[2] == "example.com")
{
    current_url[2] = "NewDomain";
}

var new_url = current_url.join('/');    
console.log('New tab url: ' + new_url);
document.location.href = new_url;
```

But it's not working, What changes should I apply?

Comment: Please ensure you're watching background page console: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/google-chrome-extension/5938/developer-tool-integration/20829/debugging-the-background-page-script

Comment: Thank you, can I write logs to chrome console ?

Comment: `console.log` is just ok, what I mean is that you should view it in right console, that is where you write where you watch. See above link and find more details how to view it in background page console

Comment: Your right. all logs are in the background page console. but how can I create logs in the chrome console (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in current tab), is it possible?

Comment: When you are saying "chrome console", do you mean the console in current web page? If so, you could take a look at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and learn how to pass the data from background page to content scripts, then you can call `console.log` in content scripts.

Comment: If you check the url on pageload instead of on button click then this will achieve the automatic that you are after.  You will probably have to use a content script and pass messages to your background script (if you can't do whatyou want in the content script)

Answer (score 0):

Use a content script instead and drop the browser_action.

Then you can use document.location.href = "urlToRedirectTo";

The url matching can be done in the manifest

You have two options.  Either specify the url to match in the manifest or match every url and check the url in the content script.

For example, this manifest will match all urls:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "whatever",
"description": "blah",
"version": "1.0",

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],

"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
]
}
```

And in the content.js, you could do something like this:

```
if (document.location.href == "theUrlImLookingFor")
    document.location.href = "theUrlThatIRedirectTo";
```

Comment: I have made some changes in my code, but with no result. could you please give me a sample code.